# Computer architecture vs organisation vs design

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

I'd started reading the corresponding topic and of what I concluded, 
am I right if say,

Computer architecture implies a list of command to the operation, where `x` command would perform a `y` operation.

Computer organization implies deciding the input and output through the hardware, corresponding to the `x` and `y`.

Computer design implies implementing the circuit to correspond to the above-mentioned computer organization.

I am a beginner in the subject and would be glad to get your reviews about my understanding of the concept.

Comment: There are no standard definitions for any of these terms. You should probably read [Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture) on computer architecture and rephrase your question based on that. Otherwise, the question in its current form will likely get closed.

Comment: The "list of instructions" is called an instruction  set, or instruction-set-architecture (ISA).  Designing ISAs is only part of computer architecture / organization.

Answer (score 0):

**Computer architecture** specifies what the hardware looks like (its interface) so that we can write software to run on it. This includes things like exactly what instructions it has, the number of storage locations, and much more.

**Computer organization** refers to the level of abstraction above the digital logic level, but below the operating system level. Here, major components are functional units (or subsystems) that correspond to specific pieces of hardware built from lower level building blocks. This is frequently called **microarchitecture**, and is the way the ISA (instruction set architecture) is implemented in the processor. There are many different microarchitectures that conform to the same architecture.

**Computer design** refers to the actual implementation (and choices) of pieces of hardware when building a computer.